# FactoryGirl throws strange error when running RSpec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have two separate Rails applications inside a folder. My file structure looks like this:

```
top_level
  app_1
  app_2
```

Inside app_1 and app_2 are the standard Rails file structures, including a spec folder for each. app_2 uses `factory_girl`, while app_1 uses `factory_girl_rails`

I have an RSpec test in app_2 which calls the factory for the `foo_bar` object, which is defined in app_2/spec/factories. This test passes successfully.

However, in app_1, which has the same definition for `foo_bar` in app_1/spec/factories, when I try to build an object with the factory, I get this error:

```
NameError:
   uninitialized constant FooBar
```

Neither of the apps has a model called FooBar. Why does the test pass on one and fail on the other?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that in the error case, the spec test wasn't seeing the factory file and was giving the error as noted above.  When I moved the factory definition into the correct location, the error message went away.